# pytest-appium: cannot start tests, got SKIPPED

Tags: plugins, appium, pytest

Trying to run tests with [pytest-appium](https://github.com/GlobalRadio/pytest-appium) plugin.
Trying to start tests as usual, without any additional cmdline arguments:
`SKIPPED [1] projects/Python/3/appium-tests/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_appium/plugin.py:8: no variables file`

When started tests with --variables=vars.json (also added corresponding file to the project):
`SKIPPED [1] projects/Python/3/appium-tests/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_appium/plugin.py:12: no "caps" or "server" in variables`

Was trying also with caps or server or altogether in vars.json, same result:
`SKIPPED [1] projects/Python/3/appium-tests/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_appium/plugin.py:12: no "caps" or "server" in variables`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you are using the wrong `pytest-appium`.
In PyPi, `pytest-appium` points to [this project](https://github.com/hanzhichao/pytest-appium), which is a very basic plugin probably created for testing purposes.

The plugin you reference seems not to be released on PyPi, so you have to clone and install it from the repositiory:

```
pip uninstall pytest-appium  # get rid of the wrong one
git clone https://github.com/GlobalRadio/pytest-appium.git
cd pytest-appium
pip install .
```